# python and redis, unclear syntax

Tags: python, redis, mining

This is copy of the code in **mining the social web** book.

I am a new in this field and with redis too. I want to understand what does `$` mean in this context. Also the print with `%s`, What does it mean?

This is the source code below (*from: [https://github.com/ptwobrussell/Mining-the-Social-Web](https://github.com/ptwobrussell/Mining-the-Social-Web/blob/master/python_code/friends_followers__friends_followers_in_common.py)*):

```
import sys
import redis

from twitter__util import getRedisIdByScreenName

# A pretty-print function for numbers
from twitter__util import pp

r = redis.Redis()
screen_names=['user1','user2']
def friendsFollowersInCommon(screen_names):
    r.sinterstore('temp$friends_in_common',
        [getRedisIdByScreenName(screen_name, 'friend_ids')
         for screen_name in screen_names]
    )

r.sinterstore('temp$followers_in_common',
    [getRedisIdByScreenName(screen_name, 'follower_ids')
     for screen_name in screen_names]
)

print 'Friends in common for %s: %s' % (', '.join(screen_names),
                                        pp(r.scard('temp$friends_in_common')))

print 'Followers in common for %s: %s' % (', '.join(screen_names),
                                          pp(r.scard('temp$followers_in_common')))

# Clean up scratch workspace

r.delete('temp$friends_in_common')
r.delete('temp$followers_in_common')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(screen_names) < 2:
        print >> sys.stderr, "Please supply at least two screen names."
        sys.exit(1)

friendsFollowersInCommon(screen_names[1:])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` symbol is just a part of key name. It separates name parts. I usually use `:` for the same purpose (e.g. `users:123`)

`%s` part is [python](/questions/tagged/python)'s [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typesseq-strings.html).

Comment: what about this part ?                          r.sinterstore('temp$followers_in_common',
    [getRedisIdByScreenName(screen_name, 'follower_ids')
     for screen_name in screen_names]

Comment: I mean, the [] the first part is method then for loop .what does this mean?

Comment: This is python's list comprehension. I suggest that you familiarize yourself with the language (python) before you learn new technology (redis).